# A counter-intuitive function call in C++

Tags: c++

A quite simple C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    void callPrint() {
        print();
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Foo" << endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Bar" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar b;
    b.callPrint();

    return 0;
}
```

Here the output is "Foo". And if I make the "Foo::print()" virtual, the output will be "Bar". My questions are:

1. When the `Foo::print()` is non-virtual, why is it called when a `Bar` object is passed to `Foo::callPrint()`, is there type (both static and dynamic) mismatch?
2. When `Foo:callPrint()` is virtual, the call `b.callPrint()` is not via reference or pointer, however `Bar::print()` is called. This is not so-called polymorphism, then how to explain this behavior, according to either language definition or compiler implementation?

Comment: any non-virtual methods called inside a method of class `Foo` will refer to `Foo`'s version. That's the whole point of `virtual`: to allow the methods of `Foo` to actually call child implementations from `Bar`.

Comment: Since `print` is not virtual, if `callPrint` called `Bar::print` in this case, it would *always* do that, which can't be right.

Comment: For even more insight, make only `Bar::print` virtual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `b.callPrint();`, control transfers to function `callPrint` in base class. Now the type of `this` is `Foo *` which points to an object of `Bar *`. Now when you call `print()` or `this->print()`

1. In case of non virtual function, the called function is decided at compile time on basis of type of `this` and thus `Foo::print` is invoked.
2. In case of virtual function, the called function is decided at run times based on the type of pointed object, and thus `Bar::print` is invoked.

---

Do you want to add more fun? Make the function `Foo::print()` a `virtual` function and call it from the constructor of `Foo` and create an object of `Bar`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I am still curious about how the static type is Foo*, is there a implicit type conversion?

Comment: @Vanilla (static) Type of `this` depends on class in which that function is declared. If function is declared in class `Foo` (static) type of this pointer if `Foo*`, if it's declared in  class `Whatever` it's (static) type os `Whatever*`.

Comment: If the control is ever in function `Foo::some_member_fun()`, type of `this` will be `Foo *`. You can visualize this as `some_member_fun()` taking `this` of type `Foo *` as last (hidden) argument. If you pass `Bar *` instead, an implicit upcasting takes place.

Comment: OK, I got it! Thank you all for answer!

Answer (score 7):

Standard has nice paragraph (10.3/9):

> [ Note: The interpretation of the call of a virtual function depends on the type of the object for which it is
>   called (the dynamic type), whereas the interpretation of a call of a non-virtual member function depends
>   only on the type of the pointer or reference denoting that object (the static type) (5.2.2). — end note ]

`print()` is called on implicit `this` whose (when dereferenced) dynamic type is `Bar`, however inside `callPrint()` it's static type is `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

1. When it is non virtual the call to `print` is not overridden by the subclass and thus prints "Foo".
2. When it is virtual the call to print is overridden by the subclass and thus the prints "Bar".

This is expected behaviour. When you declare a method as virtual then you are saying that the behaviour of the class depends on its subclasses and can (has to) be overridden. You cannot understand the behaviour of a virtual class without knowing all its subclasses.

Comment: The term is override, not overwrite!

Comment: @Roland Corrected, didn't know there is a difference between override and overwrite....